# Create Item in Podio Using Python Wrapper PyPOdio

Tags: python-3.x, api, wrapper, podio, createitem

I am unable to create an item in PODIO using PYPODIO2 wrapper and the API. I have been able to successfully authorise using OAuth App Authentication. 
Below is the snippet of code that i am trying to execute but i run into an error

```
attributes={"fields": {"module-serial": serial_number,
                       "contract-manufacturer-name-2":"Extel",
                       "module-number-and-name":{ 
                                "status": "active",
                                "text": "BD201: Main Board Extended Build",
                                "id": 2},
                       "category":{
                               "status": "active",
                               "text": "Pass",
                               "id": 1}
                       }
            }

pcbapp.Item.create(17174065, attributes)
```

> **Error:** pypodio2.transport.TransportException:
>   TransportException({'server': 'nginx', 'date': 'Tue, 07 Feb 2017
>   05:49:05 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
>   'content-length': '259', 'connection': 'keep-alive',
>   'x-rate-limit-remaining': '989', 'x-rate-limit-limit': '1000',
>   'x-podio-auth-ref': 'app_17174065', 'x-podio-request-id': 'yUWqV1ao',
>   'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31535999', 'status': '400'}):
>   {"error_parameters":{},"error_detail":null,"error_propagate":false,"request":{"url":"http://api.podio.com/item/app/17174065/","query_string":"","method":"POST"},"error_description":"Invalid
>   value null (null): Not a valid option","error":"invalid_value"}

Error description: `Invalid value null (null): Not a valid option`

Answer (score 1):

Most likely one of your fields is formatted wrong way.
You should try fill them one by one to find problematic one, and then try different formats for last one.

I would recommend you to start with category fields `module-number-and-name` and `category` and pass values like:

```
{
 ...........
 # passing array of id's only, without text and status
 "module-number-and-name" : [2], 
 "category" :               [1], 
 .........
}
```